# File Object - append data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a file object and I would like to add data to the object.

Is this possible?

For example, I wish to add a caption field to each file.

```
File {webkitRelativePath: "", lastModifiedDate: Wed Mar 12 2014 11:14:46 GMT+0000 (GMT), name: "gd.jpg", type: "image/jpeg", size: 279582…}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Adding a new property to the `File` object? But, only to one, or to all of them?

Comment: Just a file object, I wish to add a new attribute, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify any object in javascript. You want a new property? Just add it:

```
//assign a caption to a File object.
file.caption = 'file caption';
```

Of course, the `File` object is not aware of this property, so it will be useless except if you use it. Be aware that getting the File reference again (if you drop the variable, so the browser destroys it) and you get it again, your property won't be there. You have to store the reference for as long as you need it.

Comment: This does not work, it's not actually added to the file object, I need something that is added to the file object.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the file object', then? I think I'm not getting what you are trying to achieve. Explain what you need the `caption` property for.